# Search and Change only 1 number of a 2-D array

Tags: java, arrays, 2d

Let me first say, this is a "Lab" that I'm doing for class, and I've been working on this second of two programs for around 5 hours now, probably 2 of them stuck on this one part.  Let me first give you the requirements of the program so that maybe all of this will make a bit more sense.

> A theater seating chart is implemented as a two-dimensional array of
>   ticket prices, like this:

```
 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 
 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 
 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 
 10 10 20 20 20 20 20 20 10 10 
 10 10 20 20 20 20 20 20 10 10 
 10 10 20 20 20 20 20 20 10 10
 20 20 30 30 40 40 30 30 20 20 
 20 30 30 40 50 50 40 30 30 20
 30 40 50 50 50 50 50 50 40 30
```

> Write a program that prompts users to pick either a seat or a price.
>   Mark sold seats by changing the price to 0. When a user specifies a
>   seat, make sure it is available. When a user specifies a price, find
>   any seat with that price.

That's the book's description, here's what my professor has given me to go with as well.

> Required Program Components: The initial seating chart in this
>   solution is generated as shown in the example. The solution also
>   assumes that the user will enter a row and seat which start at 1 and
>   where row 1 is the bottom front row. Your program should have at least
>   3 static methods that i) print the array, ii) sellSeatByPrice, and
>   iii)sellSeatByNumber. Please declare and initialize your array to the
>   provided seat price values in main.

What I've gotten myself stuck on for around 2 hours is figuring out how to change just one of the numbers of the 2D array to a 0.  Say I entered a seat for 30, I've changed my code around 5 times now to get it to work and I'll either have every 30 change to a 0, or a few of them, or none.  The main portion I need help on is the method called sellSeatByPrice().  Currently I'm not getting any numbers to change. Here's my current full code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Theater
{
   static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
   static int[][] seatingChart;

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
       seatingChart = new int[][] { 
          { 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10 },
          { 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10 }, 
          { 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10 }, 
          { 10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 10, 10 }, 
          { 10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 10, 10 }, 
          { 10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 10, 10 },
          { 20, 20, 30, 30, 40, 40, 30, 30, 20, 20 },
          { 20, 30, 30, 40, 50, 50, 40, 30, 30, 20 },
          { 30, 40, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 40, 30 },
       }; 
       System.out.println("Welcome to the Box Office Program.");                //Introduction Statements
       System.out.println("Please note that seats are arranged such that");
       System.out.println("row 1, column 1, is the bottom front row.");
       System.out.println("Also, a zero denotes the seat is already sold.");
       printSeats(seatingChart);
       char response = 'Y';
       while ((response == 'Y') || (response == 'y'))
       {
       System.out.print("Pick by Seat <s>, Price <p>, or Quit <q>: ");
       char choice = in.next().charAt(0);
           switch (choice)
            {
               case'S':case's':
               { sellSeatByNumber(seatingChart);
                   break; }
               case'P':case'p':
               { sellSeatByPrice(seatingChart);
                   break; }
               case'Q':case'q':
               { System.out.print("Thank you, come again!");
                   System.exit(0); }
               default:
               { System.out.println("Error: Invalid choice."); }
            }
           System.out.print("Would you like to reserve another seat (Y/N)?: ");
        response = in.next().charAt(0);
       }
       System.out.print("Thank you, come again!");
       }

   public static void printSeats(int seatingChart[][])
   {
       for(int i=0; i<seatingChart.length; i++)
       {
           for(int j=0; j<seatingChart[i].length; j++)
           {
               if (j>0)
                   System.out.print("\t");
                   System.out.print(seatingChart[i][j]);
           }
           System.out.println();
       }
   }




   public static void sellSeatByPrice(int seatingChart[][])
   {
       System.out.print("Please enter a price for the seat you would like: ");
       int price = in.nextInt();
       boolean found = false;
       for (int i=0;i<9;i++)
         for (int j=0;j<10;j++)
            if ((found == true)&&(seatingChart[i][j]==price))
            { seatingChart[i][j]=0; break; }

        printSeats(seatingChart);


   }

   public static void sellSeatByNumber(int seatingChart[][])
   {
       System.out.println("Enter a row, then enter a seat number.");
       System.out.print("What row would you like to sit on?:");
       int row = in.nextInt();
       row = Math.abs(row-9);
       System.out.print("What seat of that row would you like to sit in?:");
       int col = in.nextInt();
       col -= 1;
       if (seatingChart[row][col]!=0)
       {
           seatingChart[row][col] = 0;
           printSeats(seatingChart);
           System.out.println("Your seat has been reserved and reflected with a 0 on the chart now.");
       }
       else { System.out.println("Sorry, that seat is already taken."); }
   }
}
```

(I do apologize if this looks sloppy, it's 3am and I can't think anymore)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method must look something like:

```
public static void sellSeatByPrice(int seatingChart[][])
{
   System.out.print("Please enter a price for the seat you would like: ");
   int price = in.nextInt();
   // boolean found = false;
   out: for (int i=0;i<9;i++)
     for (int j=0;j<10;j++)
        if (seatingChart[i][j]==price)
        { seatingChart[i][j]=0; break out; } // Notice this change

    printSeats(seatingChart);


}
```

Comment: Thank you VERY much! You just don't know how happy I am.  And to think all it took was removing 1 line, and adding like 15 characters.  Once again thank you, thank you, thank you.

Comment: Also, if I might ask, what does "out" do?

Comment: There is a label `out:` at the outer loop. `break out;` therefore takes the control out of outer loop. You may use any label name instead of out.

Comment: Interesting.  I'll keep that in mind for future reference and usage.  You learn something new everyday. :)

Comment: Yes, this trick comes handy many times, especially if there are many inner loops.

Answer (score 0):

First, you check `found == true` (which can be shortened to `if (found)`, by the way). `found` is initialized to `false` and is never touched again, so the check fails every time.

You don't even need a boolean variable here. Iterate over the seats; if a seat has the price you're looking for, set the seat's price to 0, print the array and return (`break` only exits the inner `for` loop).

Comment: You gave me what I needed, but Sourabh gave me what I wanted lol.  I needed an explanation to what I should do, and not the code, but I do appreciate the help. :)